# HTML CSS Navigation Bar: image alignment and sizing

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML + CSS code:

```css
html {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0;
  min-width: 320px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav#main-nav {
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

#container-logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

@media (max-device-width: 640px),
(max-width: 640px) {
  #container-logo {
    width: 60px;
  }
}

#container-logo a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container-logo img {
  content: url("http://www.dummymag.com//media/img/dummy-logo.png");
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 40px;
}

@media (max-device-width: 640px),
(max-width: 640px) {
  #container-logo img {
    content: url("http://coachmikelee.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/dummy-logo.png");
  }
}

#container-searchbar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

#container-loginstate {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}

@media (max-device-width: 640px),
(max-width: 640px) {
  #container-loginstate {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="template.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav id="main-nav">
    <div id="container-logo">
      <a href="template.php" title="RioAulas Home"><img></a>
    </div>

    <div id="container-searchbar"></div>

    <div id="container-loginstate"></div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically it is a responsive *Top Horizontal Navigation Bar* template divided in 3 areas:

- logo at left (white)
- search bar in the middle (orange)
- login state at right (blue)

As expected, if you resize the window, all this areas will resize accordingly. Including the media queries break-point at 640px.

**Question**
Although functionally the code is performing as expected, it seems to me that there is a lot of gimmicks through the CSS code in order to properly align and size the logo picture (ex: anchor tag as flexbox with width + height being set).
Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: You're better off putting all your media queries in one place rather than dotted around. If they're all in one place it makes it much easier to find in future.

Comment: When you use background images in CSS but want them to behave like a `<img>`, it's always going to create extra work. You could use [`srcset`](https://www.google.com/search?q=srcset&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS743US743&oq=srcset&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1199j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @SamJohnson not necessarily, that was the convention initially but over the last few years developers have begun to place the media query where required. This way you don't have to jump to the `@medai (xxxx) {}` block to see if a style is actually being used at the particular breakpoint.

Comment: @hungerstar oh ok interesting. I suppose it comes down to personal preference. I feel like it'd be annoying to type out the media query for the same device/size for each element that needs adjusting.

Comment: @SamJohnson that's why you use a CSS pre-processor.

Comment: @hungerstar _"You could use srcset"_ I have the impression that most of the gimmicks are related to the anchor tag CSS code => `width: 100%; height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`. I don't see how `srcset` would simplify that.

Comment: @SamJohnson _"You're better off putting all your media queries in one place"_ When there are several media queries I agree with you, most likely you are better off grouping them all together. But in this case there is so few. I don't see much benefits grouping them all together in one single place.

Answer (score -2):

i agree with you, its seem to be a bit too gimmicky. I used your code with inline-block, and floats, the problem is container-searchbar's width.

Comment: _"I used your code with inline-block, and floats"_ Mind to post that code?

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. Please earn 50 rep to comment.

Comment: nav#main-nav div {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
}
nav#main-nav {
 display:block;
}
This does not solve your problem(sorry), as now you have an issue with the width for the container-searchbar div. Also,you might be able to remove the display :flex, and use line-height to vertical position the img/a tag

Comment: _"now you have an issue with the width for the container-searchbar"_ In the past there was a technique to `float: right` the login container and let logo (fix width) + search container (variable width) goes with the flow. I guess this would solve the issue you've mentioned. However, this requires messing up with the natural order of the lines in the HTML file (one of the reasons flexbox was developed).